# Meaning of $\vee$ in context of $\sigma-$ Algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation, random-variables

Consider i.i.d random variables $X(t)$ for $t=0,...,T$ and there corresponding $\sigma-$algebra $\sigma(X(1),...,X(t))$.

Why can I state the following:  $$\sigma(X(1),...,X(t+1))= \sigma(X(1),...,X(t)) \vee \sigma(X(t+1))$$

What does $\vee$ mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2 $\sigma$-algebras $A$ and $B$, $A \vee B = \sigma(A \cup B)$.

In this case, we have

$$\sigma(X(1),...,X(t)) \vee \sigma(X(t+1)) = \sigma(\sigma(X(1),...,X(t)) \cup \sigma(X(t+1))) = \sigma(X(1),...,X(t+1))$$

Comment: Thank you very much:)